# How do I add a reference to a aar file in android studio using a URL to the aar file?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, jcenter

I have an aar file publicly available for use by clients. It is downloadable from a URL. How can I add a reference to the library in an android app?

I understand I need to upload it to bintray/jcenter/mavencentral for it to work with versioning. But that is not an option right now.

Is there a free repository I can host on my servers to expose the library?

Comment: Download the file and include it in the project.

Comment: But if I update the aar file, the consumer will not get the latest file, right?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand I need to upload it to bintray/jcenter/mavencentral for it to work with versioning

No. You need to have it be in a repository for it to work with versioning. You are welcome to create your own repository. A Maven-style artifact repository is merely a particular directory structure, along with metadata files and your AAR.

For example, I distribute my libraries through a Maven-style repository that I host on Amazon S3.